# tcsh login shell with command

Tags: linux, shell, tcsh

I'd like to have tcsh start a login shell and execute a command.

I tried this:

```
tcsh -l -c ls
```

But got this error message:

```
Unknown option: `-l'
Usage: tcsh [ -bcdefilmnqstvVxX ] [ argument ... ].
```

This [doc](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.bpxa500/cshell.htm) corrected my understanding; -l can only be used if it's the only argument. But, said doc also indicated that specifying '-' would work, but that resulted in a different error:

```
> tcsh - -c ls
-: No such file or directory.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens if you pipe into `tcsh -l`?  For example `echo "ls" | tcsh -l`

Answer (score 2):

You're misunderstanding what it says about `-`, although I admit that the wording is confusing. It says that argument **0** has to be `-`. Argument 0 is the name of the program itself, not the arguments after the command on the command line.

The way it actually works is if `argv[0]` *begins* with `-`, it runs as a login shell. Checking the first character of `argv[0]` is how shells normally detect that they're being run during a login. This is because when you login for real, the system executes your login shell with no arguments, but adds a `-` prefix before the shell name. You can see this in `ps`, you'll often see commands like `-tcsh` and `-bash` -- those are login shells.

As suggested in the comments, you can do what you want by piping the command to the shell's standard input:

```
echo ls | tcsh -l
```